# Is it possible to store a Javascript function in memory for use on multiple pages of site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

I have a long javascript function (about 72k minified) that is required on several pages of my site. My existing method to employ the function on my pages is to call the script by the usual means:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/complex_function.js"></script>
```

However, this involves reading and parsing the script on each page on which it is required. If I could store the function in my browser's memory and simply call it from there, then it would seem more efficient and faster (yes?)

Sadly, it seems that sessionStorage only supports the storages of keys and values that are strings. I've tried stringifying the function (as discussed elsewhere re: Javascript objects being stored in sessionStorage or localStorage), like so:

```
// First call the function in an initial page of the site:
<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/complex_function.js"></script>
// Then stringify it and store in sessionStorage:
sessionStorage.setItem('my_function', JSON.stringify(my_function));
```

Thereafter, in theory, I should be able to retrieve the function from sessionStorage anywhere session is active on my site, like this:

```
var temp = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('my_function');
```

...although (1) this doesn't work, or at least I can't find a way to make it work, and (2) even if I could make it work, it would still involve parsing the function, which would defeat the purpose (right?)

So...what is the best way to store a Javascript function in memory (no cookies, please) so that it can be called from any page on my site? (Or is this possible at all?)

Comment: you can only store `js` file in browser cache

Comment: Depending on how the website is hosted and requests are made to the Javascript file, you can have it cached... Basically returns a 304 status for the file when requested - i.e. "Not Modified"

Comment: How long does it take to interpret the function?

Comment: By memory I do mean cache. But is reading something from the cache faster than reading it from a file?

Comment: load the script in a page, and load all your subpages in iframes on that page

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will already do this for you. It will cache scripts upon their first download to reduce loading times, so once it's loaded the first time successive requests for that file will be quicker as it is pulled from the local machine, not the server.

Comment: OP specifically states that he wish to save time on parsing of the function.

Comment: What do you mean by 'parsing of the function'? If you mean the time of the JS file to load, see my answer. If you're talking about caching the result of the function then the OP doesn't mention that at all.

Comment: @Rory By 'parsing' I do mean evaluating & running. The routine performs conditional changes on each page on which it is called, and therefore there are no 'results' or 'return values' to store; it's the routine itself (~74kb minified) that I wish to load as quickly as possible so that it can do its work on the page in question.

Comment: Then my answer is still relevant.

Comment: `..even if I could make it work, it would still involve parsing the functiom, , which would defeat the purpose ` So I'd say OP did mention it. Whether OP should actually be concerned with the parsing/interpretation time is different and the reason to my comment to the OP

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I don't think it's a good idea to store js functions in memory.
And per my experiences, the `sessionStorage` only store string values, so you can try `eval()`

Comment: `eval()` will negate any benefit of 'caching' a script in sessionStorage.